# An identifying function for 2D matrices regardless of rotation or mirroring

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, matrix

Given a `List<List<Boolean>>`, so basically a 2D matrix of 0/1, I want to create a function that will identify a matrix uniquely (without collisions) *regardless* of the rotation and the mirroring. So, for each matrix there are 1-8 orientations where the identifier must be the same.

The matrices are at maximum 8x8 large. Uniqueness in this sense means, that if there exists a way of rotation/mirroring actions that can translate into another matrix, the function should return the same checksum/identifier for both. Otherwise, it must be different.

I feel this should be a solved problem, but I am missing the right words to search for it.

Comment: I don't know if there is a ready to use algorithm for this, but please note a whole matrix can be represented as a single long value. You can create a set of such long values, then comparing matrices is very easy.

Comment: You could sort the eight versions and keep only the first. That bakes it down to a Long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we can serialize our matrix to a more "compressed" and flat form, which will be easier to compare. As the matrix stores booleans, we can represent it as a sequence of bits, for example `BitSet`. In our specific example matrices are 8x8 at most, that means 64 bits, so we can actually store a matrix as a single long value.

Disclaimer: if matrices could be larger or store other data types than booleans, we could use a similar approach, but matrices would take more space in a serialized form.

If we rotate the matrix to all 8 variants and serialize each of them, we get 8 values. Then we have two options:

1. Store all 8 values, potentially with references between them. When we have another matrix to compare, we serialize it and look if we know the value.
2. Chose one of these values in a deterministic way, for example the minimum one. Then when we have another matrix, create its 8 variants, serialize them, choose the minimum and compare.

As you asked to create a single-value checksum of a matrix, we'll do the second option.

Let's start by creating an interface for our matrix - it will be helpful a bit later:

```kotlin
private const val SIZE = 4

fun interface Matrix<T> {
    operator fun get(y: Int, x: Int): T
}

fun <T> List<List<T>>.asMatrix() = Matrix { y, x -> this[y][x] }
```

For simplicity, we use a const size and support only square matrices. In practice, we probably need to support matrices of arbitrary sizes.

We can serialize a matrix of booleans pretty easily:

```kotlin
fun Matrix<Boolean>.serialize(): Long {
    var ret = 0L
    for (y in 0 until SIZE) {
        for (x in 0 until SIZE) {
            ret = ret.shl(1)
            if (this[y, x]) {
                ret++
            }
        }
    }
    return ret
}
```

Now we need to mirror and rotate. It would be probably the best for the performance to do it in already serialized form - then we can use bit operations. However, that would be pretty hard to read, so instead we'll use a very simple trick - translate offsets of matrices:

```kotlin
fun <T> Matrix<T>.rotated() = Matrix { y, x -> this[x, y] }
fun <T> Matrix<T>.mirroredX() = Matrix { y, x -> this[y, SIZE - x - 1] }
fun <T> Matrix<T>.mirroredY() = Matrix { y, x -> this[SIZE - y - 1, x] }
```

The remaining part is to create all 8 variations, serialize all of them and pick the minimum:

```kotlin
fun Matrix<Boolean>.checksum() = allVariations().minOf { it.serialize() }

fun <T> Matrix<T>.allVariations() = sequenceOf(this, rotated())
    .flatMap { sequenceOf(it, it.mirroredX()) }
    .flatMap { sequenceOf(it, it.mirroredY()) }
```

Let's see it in action:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    listOf(
        listOf(false, false, false, false),
        listOf(true, true, false, false),
        listOf(false, true, true, false),
        listOf(false, false, false, false),
    ).asMatrix().checksum().let { println(it) } // 612

    listOf(
        listOf(false, false, false, false),
        listOf(false, false, true, false),
        listOf(false, true, true, false),
        listOf(false, true, false, false),
    ).asMatrix().checksum().let { println(it) } // 612

    listOf(
        listOf(false, false, false, false),
        listOf(false, true, true, false),
        listOf(false, true, true, false),
        listOf(false, true, false, false),
    ).asMatrix().checksum().let { println(it) } // 1634
}
```

It is helpful to have a simple util to dump the contents of a matrix:

```kotlin
fun Matrix<Boolean>.print() {
    for (y in 0 until SIZE) {
        for (x in 0 until SIZE) {
            print(if (this[y, x]) "X" else ".")
        }
        println()
    }
}
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, we need only a single mirroring operation. Rotation swaps dimensions, so we can use it to mirror in both dimensions. But that would complicate a bit.